# How to hook up old repository history to a new repository that already has commits?

Tags: git, github

I've moved my repository to another location on my local system, and I used the `git init` command, which made a new repository and created an entirely new history system. I've made a few commits since that happened. The commits on the old local system do not show up on the current local system, which is to be expected, since I made a completely new repository. The commits only exist on GitHub now, and I can only see them because I put tags on those commits. When I go back to those commits, this shows:

[image: Warning on GitHub]

The old commits on the old local system don't show up on the new local environment, because the history was empty, so `git reflog` does not show the older commits on GitHub.

Git, in the local environment, treats the commits as if they do not exist/are not part of the branch, but I want those commits to be added back onto the tree, so it's easy for me to compare them with each other. (Trying to compare the commits that are not part of the new commit tree shows that they have entirely different commit histories, even though the new commits are changes from the older commits.)

`git rebase` and `git cherry-pick` does not work, I've tried those already. `git merge` does not work, because, in a rush, I've deleted the old local system. The only proof that the commits from the old system exist is the fact that they're on GitHub and have tags attached to them.

In short, I want to add a bunch of commits that are on GitHub to the history of another repository, which already has commits, and push it back onto GitHub so it appears that all those commits are on the same timeline.

Comment: What does "when I try to go back to the old commit" mean? What do you do?

Comment: It's not an error at all; nothing is broken, nothing needs to be "fixed". You can connect the commit to a branch if you want to keep it -- the easiest way to do that is `git checkout -b pick_a_branch_name_here` -- or check the reflog to see what old commits exist. I don't know why you'd expect rebase or cherry-pick to fix this if you're running them while not connected to a branch; you'd need to check out a branch first and then cherry-pick your lost committish into it; adding more commits onto the lost one doesn't make it less lost.

Comment: (to be clear, the usual way to go back to a branch is `git checkout`; just be sure you're checking out something like `main`, not `origin/main` or a committish; the latter is how you get into this state in the first place).

Comment: @matt Sorry for not informing you, I've edited the post

Comment: @CharlesDuffy checked `git reflog`, those commits do not exist

Comment: "Do not exist" means what? That they're not in the reflog, or that the reflog shows things you can't checkout? (For that matter, what did you mean by "those commits"? -- typically, it's better to [edit] the question to add more details rather than addressing comments in comments, as comments are necessarily very short and unformatted)

Comment: (yes, `git init` _is_ a completely new repository, so it doesn't contain anything you made previously; that's normal and expected)

Comment: ...and just because you give two branches the same name doesn't make them "the same branch". They're only the same branch if they have common history; the name has nothing to do with it. (If you have two branches you want to merge, you need to... well... _merge_ them; that's what `git merge` is for; though of course prior to the merge point they're still distinct).

Comment: (Still, I hold to my original statement: "This commit does not belong to any branch on the repository" is a warning, not an error; it serves to let people know that any further work they do won't be attached to a named branch; it doesn't mean anything's _wrong_ as such, and there are plenty of deliberate, non-erroneous, normal ways to get into that state, like `git checkout origin/main` or `git checkout HEAD^`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I've added a little more context, let me know if there's something missing

Comment: First: Add github _as a remote_ (with `git remote add`). Second: Run `git fetch` from that remote. Once you've done that, you should see remote git branches in `git branch -r`. After you see the remote branches, you can make local branches that track them (which may or may not be named the same as the remote branches, your choice; see the `--track` and `--set-upstream-to` options in `git branch`).

Comment: So when I'm talking about merging, I mean you merge the _remote_ branch into a local branch (merge won't do anything useful to you here if you aren't on a local branch first). If you added the remote under the name `origin`, then you'd `git merge origin/yourbranchname` if you need to keep any local history and not just discard it in favor of the remote branch's contents. (If you want to discard local history, then you can just do a `git reset origin/yourbranchname` and there you are, again assuming `origin` is the name you used when adding the remote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new branch at the old commits, merged the branch with the old commits to the current commits and then pushed that back onto GitHub, so it appears that all the commits have one shared history.